# Add Additional Objects in JSON

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am currently using a JSON encoded array to display the title in my database for an auto-suggest feature.

It looks something like this:

```
<?php
require_once('./includes/config.php');
require_once('./includes/skins.php');

mysql_connect($conf['host'], $conf['user'], $conf['pass']);
mysql_select_db($conf['name']);

    $query2012 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM imdb WHERE poster !='posters/noposter.jpg' ORDER BY RAND() DESC LIMIT %d;", 8);
    $result = mysql_query($query2012);



    //Create an array
    $json_response = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['title'] = $row['title'];
        $row_array['year'] = $row['year'];
        $row_array['poster'] = $row['poster'];

        //push the values in the array
        array_push($json_response,$row_array);


    }

    echo json_encode($json_response);

    //Close the database connection
    fclose($db);

?>
```

This returns:

```
[{"title":"The Woman","year":"2011","poster":"posters\/tt1714208.jpg"},{"title":"DeadHeads","year":"2011","poster":"posters\/tt1273207.jpg"},{"title":"The Innkeepers","year":"2011","poster":"posters\/tt1594562.jpg"},{"title":"John Carter","year":"2012","poster":"posters\/tt0401729.jpg"},{"title":"American Reunion","year":"2012","poster":"posters\/tt1605630.jpg"},{"title":"The Avengers","year":"2012","poster":"posters\/tt0848228.jpg"},{"title":"Chronicle","year":"2012","poster":"posters\/tt1706593.jpg"},{"title":"Big Miracle","year":"2012","poster":"posters\/tt1430615.jpg"}]
```

**First**, how would I manually add an additional object to this output? For example, let's say I wanted to add:  `{"status":"ok","message":"Success","data":`

```
{"status":"ok","message":"Success","data":[{"title":"The Woman","year":"2011","poster":"posters\/tt1714208.jpg"},{"title":"DeadHeads","year":"2011","poster":"posters\/tt1273207.jpg"},{"title":"The Innkeepers","year":"2011","poster":"posters\/tt1594562.jpg"},{"title":"John Carter","year":"2012","poster":"posters\/tt0401729.jpg"},{"title":"American Reunion","year":"2012","poster":"posters\/tt1605630.jpg"},{"title":"The Avengers","year":"2012","poster":"posters\/tt0848228.jpg"},{"title":"Chronicle","year":"2012","poster":"posters\/tt1706593.jpg"},{"title":"Big Miracle","year":"2012","poster":"posters\/tt1430615.jpg"}]}
```

and if mysql record not found show json output

```
{"status":"error","message":"No Reord found"}
```

how i can add this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your $json_response array before encoding (`json_encode()` by modifying it structute:

```
$json_response = array(
    'data' => $json_response,
    'status' => 'ok',
    'message' => 'Successs'
);
```

You can also modify appending data to your final result variable so while you define your $json_response array add subarray:

```
$json_response = array('data' => array());
```

and in while loop add index *data*:

```
array_push($json_response['data'], $row_array);
```

And after loop you can easily append your status and message by:

```
$json_response['status'] = 'ok';
$json_response['message'] = 'Success';
```

---

To add error just check if the data array is empty. For first solution:

```
if (empty($json_response)) {
    $json_response = array(
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => 'No Reord found'
    );
} else {
    //  here append success message
}
```

In second case just change a if condition to:

```
if (empty($json_response['data']))
```